# Make sure that this accessibility bypass is safe here -- BindingFlags.NonPublic

Tags: sonarqube

VirtualizingStackPanel vsp =
(VirtualizingStackPanel)typeof(ItemsControl).InvokeMember("_itemsHost",
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic, null,
listBox, null);

I am getting the SonarQube Error

Make sure that this accessibility bypass is safe here -- BindingFlags.NonPublic

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This rule discourages using Reflection to access non-public fields.
If you must, use `#pragma warning disable S3011` in your code.